# TFS No test assemblies found matching the pattern

Tags: c#, tfs, asp.net-core-mvc, automated-tests, xunit.net

I am newbie to TFS and got legacy project. Application is ASP.NET Core MVC, it uses .NET Core 6.0.
I wanted to run unit test in TFS. This is settings that I've found recently:

[image]

But tests are not run. It says:

```
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2659415Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2733935Z ==============================================================================
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2757377Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2779733Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2798473Z Version      : 2.3.28
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2804727Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2815189Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2023-02-10T08:11:39.2846404Z ==============================================================================
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1471485Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1487886Z ========================================================
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1509812Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1524013Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\*Foo.Bar.TestLibrary.dll,!**\*testhost.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1538632Z Test filter criteria : null
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1549192Z Search folder : D:\TfsAgents\dotNetDefault\_work\2\s
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1557662Z Run settings file : D:\TfsAgents\dotNetDefault\_work\2\s
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1565805Z Run in parallel : true
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1570553Z Run in isolation : false
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1592991Z Path to custom adapters : null
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1598283Z Other console options : null
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1603518Z Code coverage enabled : true
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1612353Z Rerun failed tests: false
2023-02-10T08:11:40.1619914Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2023-02-10T08:11:40.5178061Z ========================================================
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9180802Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9191874Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9204400Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9214640Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9224315Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9238856Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9250308Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9259790Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9275781Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9296315Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9317966Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9337844Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9358059Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9373710Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9383130Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9392781Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9402054Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9411443Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9420659Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9431366Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9442896Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9454959Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9468304Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9478978Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9490804Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9502277Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9514008Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9526112Z (node:19236) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9555091Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*test*.dll,!**\*Foo.Bar.TestLibrary.dll,!**\*testhost.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**.
2023-02-10T08:12:33.9926468Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

Or shorter version is:

```
No test assemblies found matching the pattern: 
**\*test*.dll,!**\*Foo.Bar.TestLibrary.dll,
!**\*testhost.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
```

I've read this topic and added an extra wildcard:

```
**\*\*test*.dll
!**\*\*Foo.Bar.TestLibrary.dll
```

Even I've added two extra spaces. However, the error message is still the same.

```
**\*\*\*test*.dll
!**\*\*\*Foo.Bar.TestLibrary.dll
```

This is version of TFS:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.131.28601.4
© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Do the tests work if you run `dotnet test`? I actually have no idea if `vstest.console` will discover and run modern .NET 3.1/5/6 tests, as opposed to "classic" .NET framework tests.

Comment: @DanielMann Do you mean that these TFS test step is for 'classic' .NET framework, not for '.NET Core'? Wow, I am really ashamed. Could you please reply and I will mark it as an asnwer. Thanks!

Comment: That's *probably* the case, but not *definitely*.